# Connecting to PostgreSQL: Postico and TablePlus DB GUIs can't connect but `psql` in Docker works (FATAL: password authentication failed for user)

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, postico

I have deployed my PostgreSQL database locally with Docker. This is my Docker Compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.30-alpha
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "4466:4466"
    environment:
      PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        port: 4466
        # uncomment the next line and provide the env var PRISMA_MANAGEMENT_API_SECRET=my-secret to activate cluster security
        # managementApiSecret: my-secret
        prototype: true
        databases:
          default:
            connector: postgres
            host: postgres
            user: prisma
            password: prisma
            port: 5432
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: prisma
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: prisma
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  postgres:
```

I've started this with `docker-compose up -d`.

The Docker containers are running:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                             COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
26b14120f89f        prismagraphql/prisma:1.30-alpha   "/bin/sh -c /app/sta…"   17 minutes ago      Up 17 minutes       0.0.0.0:4466->4466/tcp   newdm1_prisma_1
05dfdaeaf609        postgres                          "docker-entrypoint.s…"   17 minutes ago      Up 17 minutes       5432/tcp                 newdm1_postgres_1
```

Now, for some reason **I can't connect using a database GUI** (having tried Postico and TablePlus). In both clients, I get the following error:

> FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "prisma"

I'm 100% sure that I'm providing `prisma` as the password as specified in the Docker Compose file.

Also, when I'm connecting to the database using `psql` from inside the `postgres` Docker container, it does work:

```
docker exec -it 05dfdaeaf609 bash
```

Then inside the Docker container I do this:

```
root@05dfdaeaf609:/# psql -U prisma -W prisma
Password: 
psql (11.1 (Debian 11.1-1.pgdg90+1))
Type "help" for help.

prisma=# \l
                              List of databases
   Name    | Owner  | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    | Access privileges 
-----------+--------+----------+------------+------------+-------------------
 postgres  | prisma | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | 
 prisma    | prisma | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | 
 template0 | prisma | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/prisma        +
           |        |          |            |            | prisma=CTc/prisma
 template1 | prisma | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/prisma        +
           |        |          |            |            | prisma=CTc/prisma
(4 rows)

prisma=# \c prisma
Password for user prisma: 
You are now connected to database "prisma" as user "prisma".
```

The password I've provided inside `psql` was `prisma`, similar to the ones I've provided inside Postico and TablePlus.

Is there anything special I need to do when connecting to a PostgreSQL DB in a Docker container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PORTS
0.0.0.0:4466->4466/tcp
5432/tcp
```

If you check the ports column of `docker ps` command, you would realize that the Postgres port is not exposed to be used by the host machine.

To solve this, you need to add the following to the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
ports:
  - "5432:5432"
```

Making the full file look like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.30-alpha
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "4466:4466"
    environment:
      PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        port: 4466
        # uncomment the next line and provide the env var PRISMA_MANAGEMENT_API_SECRET=my-secret to activate cluster security
        # managementApiSecret: my-secret
        prototype: true
        databases:
          default:
            connector: postgres
            host: postgres
            user: prisma
            password: prisma
            port: 5432
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: prisma
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: prisma
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  postgres:
```

and then you need to run `docker-compose up -d` to apply the new changes. When setup correctly, the `PORTS` column of `docker ps` should look like this

```
PORTS
0.0.0.0:4466->4466/tcp
0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp
```